# children.innerText is not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

i have a html like this:

```
<div class="tree" id="divTreeViewIncomeDetails" style="height: auto;">
            <li><span class="fa fa-folder-open highlight" id="3" onmouseover="visibleLink('3', 'Incomes', '0')" onmouseout="hideLink('3')"><span onclick="GetTreeViewChartOfAccountsByParam('3', 'Incomes')">Incomes </span><span class="closingbalance">INR 50.00Dr </span></span>
                <ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li><span class="fa fa-file chartwidth" id="84" onmouseover="visibleLink('84', 'Sales A/c', '1')" onmouseout="hideLink('84')" onclick="ViewLedgerMsg(84)"><span onclick="GetTreeViewChartOfAccountsByParam('84', 'Sales A/c')">Sales A/c </span><span class="closingbalance">INR 50.00Dr </span></span></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li><span class="fa fa-folder-open chartwidth" id="98" onmouseover="visibleLink('98', 'Indirect Income', '1')" onmouseout="hideLink('98')"><span onclick="GetTreeViewChartOfAccountsByParam('98', 'Indirect Income')">Indirect Income </span><span class="closingbalance">INR 0.00Cr </span></span>
                            <ul>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><span class="fa fa-file chartwidth" id="99" onmouseover="visibleLink('99', 'Realized Exchange Gain', '2')" onmouseout="hideLink('99')" onclick="ViewLedgerMsg(99)"><span onclick="GetTreeViewChartOfAccountsByParam('99', 'Realized Exchange Gain')">Realized Exchange Gain </span><span class="closingbalance">INR 0.00Cr </span></span></li>
                                </ul>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><span class="fa fa-file chartwidth" id="122" onmouseover="visibleLink('122', 'Rounding off Gain A/c', '2')" onmouseout="hideLink('122')" onclick="ViewLedgerMsg(122)"><span onclick="GetTreeViewChartOfAccountsByParam('122', 'Rounding off Gain A/c')">Rounding off Gain A/c </span><span class="closingbalance">INR 0.00Cr </span></span></li>
                                </ul>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><span class="fa fa-file chartwidth" id="124" onmouseover="visibleLink('124', 'Discount Received A/c', '2')" onmouseout="hideLink('124')" onclick="ViewLedgerMsg(124)"><span onclick="GetTreeViewChartOfAccountsByParam('124', 'Discount Received A/c')">Discount Received A/c </span><span class="closingbalance">INR 0.00Cr </span></span></li>
                                </ul>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><span class="fa fa-file chartwidth" id="140" onmouseover="visibleLink('140', 'Stock Income', '2')" onmouseout="hideLink('140')" onclick="ViewLedgerMsg(140)"><span onclick="GetTreeViewChartOfAccountsByParam('140', 'Stock Income')">Stock Income </span><span class="closingbalance">INR 0.00Cr </span></span></li>
                                </ul>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li><span class="fa fa-file chartwidth" id="134" onmouseover="visibleLink('134', 'Clearing And Forwarding Rcd', '1')" onmouseout="hideLink('134')" onclick="ViewLedgerMsg(134)"><span onclick="GetTreeViewChartOfAccountsByParam('134', 'Clearing And Forwarding Rcd')">Clearing And Forwarding Rcd </span><span class="closingbalance">INR 0.00Cr </span></span></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li><span class="fa fa-file chartwidth" id="135" onmouseover="visibleLink('135', 'Transport charges received ', '1')" onmouseout="hideLink('135')" onclick="ViewLedgerMsg(135)"><span onclick="GetTreeViewChartOfAccountsByParam('135', 'Transport charges received ')">Transport charges received  </span><span class="closingbalance">INR 0.00Cr </span></span></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li><span class="fa fa-file chartwidth" id="156" onmouseover="visibleLink('156', 'Sales Discount A/c', '1')" onmouseout="hideLink('156')" onclick="ViewLedgerMsg(156)"><span onclick="GetTreeViewChartOfAccountsByParam('156', 'Sales Discount A/c')">Sales Discount A/c </span><span class="closingbalance">INR 0.00Cr </span></span></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li><span class="fa fa-file chartwidth" id="158" onmouseover="visibleLink('158', 'Stock Income A/c', '1')" onmouseout="hideLink('158')" onclick="ViewLedgerMsg(158)"><span onclick="GetTreeViewChartOfAccountsByParam('158', 'Stock Income A/c')">Stock Income A/c </span><span class="closingbalance">INR 0.00Cr </span></span></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li><span class="fa fa-file chartwidth" id="163" onmouseover="visibleLink('163', 'Exchange Gain A/c', '1')" onmouseout="hideLink('163')" onclick="ViewLedgerMsg(163)"><span onclick="GetTreeViewChartOfAccountsByParam('163', 'Exchange Gain A/c')">Exchange Gain A/c </span><span class="closingbalance">INR 0.00Cr </span></span></li>
                    </ul>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><span class="fa fa-arrow-down" style="width: 100%; color: red; font-weight: 700;"><span>Net Loss </span><span class="closingbalance">14,950.00Cr</span></span></li>
        </div>
```

Now i need to get the innertext of

For that i m doing this:

```
var items = [];
            var inputData = $('#divTreeViewIncomeDetails').find('li > span');

            for (var i = 0; i < inputData.length; i++) {
                var position, data1, data2;
                position = inputData[i].className;
                data1 = inputData[i].children['0'].innerText.trim();
                data2 = inputData[i].children['1'].innerText.trim();
                var item = { position: position, data1: data1, data2: data2 }
                items.push(item);
            }
```

Its working fine in IE,Chrome,Safari,Opera

But NOT in FIREFOX!!!

```
data1 = inputData[i].children['0'].innerText.trim();
```

this line i m not get the values in FF, its skips the code

Is there any alternate code for this ?

Comment: Just curious, You are using jQuery and still binding events using inline event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `textContent` instead of `innerText`

Comment: `textContent` isn't available in all versions of IE

Answer (score 2):

innerText isn't implemented in FireFox innerText isn't official.
You might want to use `textContent` which I believe works in all browsers

edit: (docs says it works in IE9 and up)

See documentation: [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent)

Small quote from the docs

> Differences from innerText
>
> Internet Explorer introduced element.innerText. The intention is
>   pretty much the same with a couple of differences:
>
> Note that while textContent gets the content of all elements,
>   including  and  elements, the mostly equivalent
>   IE-specific property, innerText, does not. innerText is also aware of
>   style and will not return the text of hidden elements, whereas
>   textContent will. As innerText is aware of CSS styling, it will
>   trigger a reflow, whereas textContent will not